# removing the empty space occupied by hidden field in CRM form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am having two subgrids one below the other

I have a tab designed using a html webresource, on click of the tabs I will show/hide the subgrids accordingly

When I hide the bottom subgrid, I don't get any problem, but when I hide the top subgrid, it hides the subgrid, but the space occupied by the subgrid is still there

```
$(".goalTab").click(function(event){
parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('CaseServicePlanContacts').setVisible(false);
parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('GoalSubgrid').setVisible(true);
});

$(".activityTab").click(function(event){
parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('GoalSubgrid').setVisible(false);
parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('CaseServicePlanContacts').setVisible(true);
});
```

[image]

I also tried using normal jQuery to hide (using `$("#parentid").hide()` ) the parent container, but its not supported in CRM. So is there a way to remove this empty space occupied by the hidden subgrid in CRM

Comment: you can use `.hide()`

Comment: yeah i tried .hide() but jQuery methods are not supported in CRM

Comment: `parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('CaseServicePlanContacts').style.display = 'none';` how about this one

Comment: when you use visibility it will still use the space but if you use display none it will not use the space

Comment: did you try display none what happened

Comment: it is not selecting the dom element when `parent.Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getByName('CaseServicePlanContacts')`  is used. it is a crm method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting your subgrids into sections and hiding the section instead. This is fully supported by CRM and should not leave empty space behind.